# Angular / RxJS Multicasting Observable of Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have an HTTP request that I want to share the results of to multiple components. The HTTP request, of course, returns an `Observable`. I want multiple components to be able to subscribe to this without triggering additional HTTP requests.

I accomplished this using a `Subject` in a component that made the HTTP request on demand and has another method to subscribe to the subject. 
 While this works - it seems like overkill and there certainly is a better way of doing this.

subject service

```
@Injectable()
export class EventService {
    subject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(Observable.create());

    constructor(private api: Api) {}

    fetch = () => {
        this.subject.next(
            this.api.getUsers().pipe(share())
        );
    };

    listen = (): Observable<any> => {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    };
}
```

and one subscriber

```
@Injectable
export class EventListenerA {
    constructor(private eventService: EventService){
        eventService.fetch(); // make initial call
        eventService.listen().subscribe(o => {
             o.subscribe(httpResponse => {
                 //do something with response
             })
        });
    }
}
```

and second subscriber

```
@Injectable
export class EventListenerB {
    constructor(private eventService: EventService){
        eventService.listen().subscribe(o => {
             o.subscribe(httpResponse => {
                 //do something else with response
             })
        });
    }
}
```

When I remove `share()` from the pipe chain, multiple network requests are made. Is there a more elegant / correct way of passing an observable to the `next` of a `Subject` ? Or another pattern altogether

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `ReplaySubject()` without giving it an initial value. This way when a component subscribes to `listen()` it will *wait* until there is data available.

There is no need to *share* the HTTP observable with other components. Just subscribe to the HTTP request and then send the value to the `ReplaySubject()`. Any components listening will receive the data.

```
@Injectable()
export class EventService {
     private _events: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);

     public constructor(private _api: ApiService) {}

     public fetch() {
         this.api.getUsers().subscribe(value => this._events.next(value));
     }

     public listen() {
         return this._events.asObservable();
     }
 }

 @Injectable
 export class EventListenerA {
     constructor(private eventService: EventService){
          eventService.fetch();
          eventService.listen().subscribe(o => {
              // prints user data
              console.log(o); 
          });
     }
}
```

Everytime someone calls `eventService.fetch()` it will trigger a HTTP request. If you one want to perform this request once, then maybe call `fetch()` from the service constructor or another spot in the application that happens only once (i.e. a module constructor).

Comment: yep, that's the ticket - that inner subscribe was a giveaway smell - I'm surprised I never saw `ReplaySubject` in any tutorials I found. Thanks!